# Check if line ends with punctuation; if not, add period

Tags: bash, unix

I want to check if a line ends with a punctuation (.,?!) and if it doesn't, then add a period.

```
A button is missing!
A button on their back allowed them to hug
A cat is carried by the scruff of its neck by a teenage boy?
A cattery is where cats are commercially housed
```

Output:

```
A button is missing!
A button on their back allowed them to hug.
A cat is carried by the scruff of its neck by a teenage boy?
A cattery is where cats are commercially housed.
```

I'm really stumped, I tried grepping the last character of a string -- any help?

Comment: What about lines like `They said "No."` and `They said "No"` and `(They were quiet and didn't say "No!")`? Does the quote count as punctuation (even though a full stop is also needed in the second one, but isn't needed in the first one)?  What about parentheses, with terminal punctation inside the parentheses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using sed:

```
sed -i.bak 's/[^[:punct:]]$/&./' file
A button is missing!
A button on their back allowed them to hug.
A cat is carried by the scruff of its neck by a teenage boy?
A cattery is where cats are commercially housed.
```

Comment: You beat me to it!  Perhaps mention what `-i.bak` does exactly

Comment: I'm curious too what `-i.bak` does

Comment: `-i.bak` is used for inline editing of input file by sed where it save original file using `.bak` extension in case you want to restore original file.

Comment: I like how this does not alter empty lines.

Comment: @glennjackman Good point. I edited my answer to handle empty lines.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '!/[[:punct:]]$/ && NF{$NF=$NF"."}1' file
```

**Explanation:**

- We look for lines that do not end with punctuation using `!/[[:punct:]]$/` regex.
- Using `&& NF` allows us to grab only non-empty lines.
- When we find such lines, we use `awk` built-in variable `$NF` which holds the value of last field.
- We add `.` to it by doing `$NF=$NF"."`
- `1` is for printing the line as it results in true.

```
$ cat file
A button is missing!
A button on their back allowed them to hug
A cat is carried by the scruff of its neck by a teenage boy?
A cattery is where cats are commercially housed
```

```
$ awk '!/[[:punct:]]$/ && NF{$NF=$NF"."}1' file
A button is missing!
A button on their back allowed them to hug.
A cat is carried by the scruff of its neck by a teenage boy?
A cattery is where cats are commercially housed.
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure bash solution, assuming your message is in the file `msg`:

```
while read
do
    r=${REPLY: -1}
    if [[ $r != "." ]] && [[ $r != "," ]] && [[ $r != "!" ]] && [[ $r != "?" ]]      
    then
        REPLY="$REPLY." 
    fi
    echo "$REPLY" 
done < msg
```

`r` is assigned the last character of `$REPLY`.

**edit**: On newer bash, you can use the `[[:punct:]]` character class and concatenate strings using `+=`. This version also doesn't add `.`s to blank lines:

```
while read
do
    if [[ ! -z "$REPLY" ]] && [[ $REPLY != *[[:punct:]] ]]
    then 
        REPLY+="."
    fi
    echo "$REPLY"
done < msg
```

Comment: +1. An enhancement: `[[ $REPLY == *[[:punct:]] ]] || REPLY+="."` (although I can't say if `+=` works in bash versions < 4). And you need to quote `"$REPLY"` when you echo it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another bash only solution using regex pattern matching, see comments for details. If have your data in a file you have to use `readarray` or a similar technique to get the data into an array. I just pasted the text into an array for the ease of use in this demo:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

text=(
    "A button is missing!"
    "A button on their back allowed them to hug."
    "A cat is carried by the scruff of its neck by a teenage boy?"
    "A cattery is where cats are commercially housed,"
    "A cattery is where cats are commercially housed" # Demo sentence missing a punctuation
)

# Regex pattern
regex="[!?,.]$"

# Counter used to call the index of the array inside the for loop
counter=0

# Iterate over each sentence inside the array
for sentence in "${text[@]}"; do

    # If a sentence does not match the regex pattern
    # append a dot.
    if [[ ! "$sentence" =~ $regex ]]; then
        text[$counter]="${sentence}."
    fi

    # Increment the counter to get the next item of the array
    (( counter++ ))
done

# We are done print the results
printf "%s\n" "${text[@]}"
```